# Is it possible to determinate the gender from a first name?

Tags: json, api

What would some approaches to this be? Do any libraries, API's etc. exist already?
How would you go about the fact that  most countries allow parents to call their kids almost anything?

Comment: I don't think that's remotely possible in the general case.

Comment: This will also be completely culture-specific.

Comment: No such beast, especially given these days when weirdo parents are giving their poor kids even weirder names. "Apple"? "Moon unit"?

Comment: I think the genderize.io approach would make up for these pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://genderize.io

It uses datasets of profiles from social networks to give a probabilistic guess. Using social profiles kind of a way to make up for the fact that children can be called anything, since a person on a social network also can choose whatever name they want.

You can also filter your guesses for a certain country or language.

GET http://api.genderize.io?name=kim

```
{"name":"kim","gender":"female","probability":"0.90","count":145}
```

GET http://api.genderize.io?name=kim&country_id=dk

```
{"name":"kim","gender":"male","probability":"1.00","count":4,"country_id":"dk"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but check this out : https://www.rapleaf.com/developers/utilities-api/utilities-api-documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I think the only real solution here is to query a large database and make a best-guess based on statistics.

The USA's Social Security agency makes available files containing DOB and Sex of every name used more than five times in the USA.

http://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html